# Textarea overflow scroller with border radius

Tags: html, css

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
}

textarea {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: none;
  background-color: blue;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
}

textarea::placeholder {
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: pink;
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
}

textarea:focus {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea>Eleifend nec eget. Id massa quis eu vitae elit. Bibendum interdum semper. Donec libero duis. Eleifend nec eget. Id massa quis eu vitae elit. Bibendum interdum semper. Donec libero duis.</textarea>
</div>
```

screenshot:

[image]

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5ptLqojg/15/

As you can see the overflow scrollbar is outside of the textarea border, I want the scrollbar not to be visible outside of the rounded corners of the textarea

notice I'm using `position: absolute;`

Comment: _What exactly_ should "synced" look like here in the first place, in your opinion ...?

Comment: Are you saying that you would like your custom scrollbar not to be visible "outside" of the rounded corners?

Comment: @CBroe


Sorry I wasn't clear, edited

Comment: @DBS yes exactly

Comment: I don't think you can get those cut off via border-radius. You might have success with a clip-path perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this trick:

```css
/* main.scss */
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.textarea-div {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 0.4rem;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  position: relative;
}
.textarea-div:focus-within {
  height: 100px;
}
.textarea-div textarea {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 290px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: none;
  background-color: blue;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.textarea-div textarea::-moz-placeholder {
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
.textarea-div textarea::placeholder {
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
.textarea-div textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 20%;
}
.textarea-div textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
}
.textarea-div textarea:focus {
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="textarea-div">
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

*SCSS File*

```scss
/* main.scss */

$textarea-width: 300px;
$textarea-height: 50px;
$textarea-height-focus: 100px;

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.textarea-div {
  width: $textarea-width;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 0.4rem;
  height: $textarea-height;
  border-radius: 16px;

  position: relative;

  &:focus-within {
    height: $textarea-height-focus;
  }

  textarea {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    width: $textarea-width - 10px;
    height: $textarea-height - 20px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    border: none;
    background-color: blue;
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 2rem;

    &::placeholder {
      vertical-align: text-top;
    }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: black;
      border-radius: 20%;
    }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 4px;
    }

    &:focus {
      height: $textarea-height-focus - 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, in my fiddle I'm using position absolute, tried your solution with it and it didn't work

Comment: I have update code with position absolute.

Comment: If you are satisfied with solution mark it as answer.